# Log what time hibernation occurred?

Tags: linux, fedora, logging, hibernate, fedora-14

```
Fedora 14 xfce
```

I am looking for the log messages where I can find out what time my netbook hibernated?

I have checked in the /var/log. And all I could see was pm-suspend.log and pm-powersave.log.

Is there one which would tell me what time my computer hibernated?

The reason for this is when I go out I leave my netbook running on the battery. When the battery get to about 5% it will hibernate. I just what to see what time it did hibernate?

Comment: Try `who -a /var/log/wtmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a thread with a couple of ideas on how you can catch the hibernate event and log it yourself: https://serverfault.com/questions/199895/how-can-i-flush-my-ssh-keys-on-power-management-activity/199896#199896
- Use dbus-python
- Write PM scripts

I have never used dbus myself, but if you need help, here are some references:
- http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus
- http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples